# WCF multiple instances of a service, 1 per thread

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, distributed-computing

Im trying to set up a distributed computing environment using WCF. I have a large amount of data to process, which i have managed to split into discrete blocks.

Is it possible to create multiple instance, 1 per core of your PC, of the same class (called NumberCruncher) and assign each to a specific EndPoint on a ServiceHost? As far as ive understood, each EndPoint needs ABC (Address (unique), Binding Info, Contract), so as long as i assign a unique EndPoint address to each instance of NumberCruncher then I should be able to access each thread, which contains a single instance of NumberCruncher?

If the above would work but is a poor solution, I'd appreciate some suggestions on a possible alternative.

Comment: Ask 1 question per question, and first check if they are not asked already and/or easy to google.

Comment: @HenkHolterman as requested, here are the other links. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466791/wcf-dealing-with-simultaneous-requests-from-multiple-servers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466839/wcf-does-the-client-have-to-call-the-server-first

Comment: I gave one of them a shot but really, you're asking for help with details of a solution that seems to be heading the wrong way. Maybe backup and ask "How to do numbercrunching on a WCF server, and supply details on the size and number of jobs.

Comment: WCF serves each request with a new instance of the service when InstanceContextMode=PerCall and this can use multi core processor, now what is the reason you want to take control of it? More reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377061.aspx